# How do I convert this to use a text file?

Tags: batch-file, text-files, delete-file

I would like to use a different method for me to whitelist my files from being deleted from a folder.

The concept would be to add the file names into a text file to keep it from being deleted. How do I accomplish this? So far this is what I have. I just don't want to go through all the brackets in the future:

```
for %%i in ("universe\*.world") do (

if /i not "%%~nxi"=="alpha_-47760677_13528428_3442937_2_8.world" (
if /i not "%%~nxi"=="alpha_-91359870_-23985140_-2679670_4_2.world" (
if /i not "%%~nxi"=="beta_-10_-18_-22519438_9.world" (
if /i not "%%~nxi"=="alpha_71479806_30568958_-29806832_11_4.world" (
if /i not "%%~nxi"=="alpha_49727000_-95701173_-4914589_9.world" (
if /i not "%%~nxi"=="gamma_-98261021_73451017_-13446340_2_5.world" (
if /i not "%%~nxi"=="test2.world" (
if /i not "%%~nxi"=="test2.world" (
if /i not "%%~nxi"=="test2.world" (
if /i not "%%~nxi"=="test2.world" (
if /i not "%%~nxi"=="test2.world" (
if /i not "%%~nxi"=="test2.world" (
del /q "%%i"

)))))))))))))
)
```

Lets say the text file I wanna pull the list from is whitelist.txt, and each line has the file name I am keeping:

```
alpha_-47760677_13528428_3442937_2_8.world
alpha_-91359870_-23985140_-2679670_4_2.world
beta_-10_-18_-22519438_9.world
alpha_71479806_30568958_-29806832_11_4.world
alpha_49727000_-95701173_-4914589_9.world
gamma_-98261021_73451017_-13446340_2_5.world
```

Or maybe even without adding ".world" extension?

Comment: your question is not very much clear

Comment: I thought it was understandable. I want to change my .bat to delete all the .world from a folder. However I want to create a whitelist via text file for the bat to read to NOT delete.

Comment: Seems perfectly clear to me - delete files matching a mask but not in a whitelist file.

Comment: `for /f %%i in (whitelist.txt) do attrib +r %%i & del /q *.world & for /f %%i in (whitelist.txt) do attrib -r %%i`  (last step optional)